# Display table names with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am kinda new to PHP and MySql and I am trying to find a way to echo the table names of my database in my page.

When I use : SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema =  'myDBname' 
directly in PHPMyAdmin, I get the results I want but I just don't know I to "echo" it in my page.

This is what I am using at the moment :

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema =  'myDBname'");
$row = $statement->fetchAll();
```

What would be, in your opinion, the best way to display it on my page if I want to eventually echo the result of the query in a dropdown menu ?

Comment: Did you try foreach? Google is your friend.

Comment: Why do you want to show tables on your page? Database table is a kind of internal information and end user should have nothing to do with it

Comment: There are reasons to show tables on your page... for instance at my job I've built an interface that gives our employees some limited access over assigning characteristics to different tables / columns, etc.

Comment: well, eventually you will have you fill find your interface broken

Comment: I tried foreach but the result is empty and I don't understand why because when I use the same query directly in phpmyadmin I get the good results. And don't worry I've been looking on Google and Stack Overflow for the past hour but I did not found anything directly related to INFORMATION_SCHEMA and displaying the results.

Comment: Nah I know what I'm doing.  They can't modify the tables / columns directly, just data connected to them.

Comment: If you're using prepare you also have to execute it.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: To Andrew Nee - I know it might not be the most secure way to do it but it's for a personal project.  I am just trying to learn more about PHP and MySQL

Comment: So a prepare + execute + foreach should work ?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
$tables = array();
$stmt = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
    $tables[] = $row[0];
}

var_dump($tables);
```